# "Перемножить" массивы String

Tags: java, массивы

Только начал изучение Java, поэтому, скорее всего, вопрос ужасно глупый.
Есть 2 массива:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] mas1 = {"слово1", "слово2", "слово3"};
            String[] mas2 = {"условие1", "условие2"};
```

В итоге мне нужно вывести следующее:

```
слово1+условие1
слово1+условие2
слово2+условие1
И т.д
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: А как вы пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое первое что приходит в голову это вложенный цикл:

```
String[] mas1 = {"слово1", "слово2", "слово3"};
String[] mas2 = {"условие1", "условие2"};

for(String s1: mas1) {
    for(String s2: mas2) {
        System.out.println(s1+"+"+s2);
    }
}
```